# Exporting data to excel from R

Tags: r, excel

How can I export my data from R to Excel without changing number format?

My dataset is composed of percentage numbers but get formatted as decimal numbers:
For.eg: `67%` is printed as `0.67`.

Is there any code to paste the numbers as they are in my source files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it depends on what type are your columns in the data frame. "dplyr::write_csv" should do the job, but note you have to convert the columns as type character to keep the structure in excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfzQs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg3Gd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is probably type character?

Anyway, try using openxlsx library to format excel sheet. Here is a simple example:

```
library(openxlsx)

df <- data.frame(pct1 = c(0.07, 0.22), pct2 = c(0.07, 0.22))

#header style
hs <- createStyle(textDecoration = "bold", wrapText = FALSE, halign = "center", valign = "center")
#style
s1 <- createStyle(numFmt = "0.0%") #1 decimal place
s2 <- createStyle(numFmt = "PERCENTAGE") #2 decimal places (default)

wb <- createWorkbook("")
addWorksheet(wb, "test")
writeData(wb, 1, df, startCol = 1, startRow = 1, headerStyle = hs)
#autosize imena emailov
setColWidths(wb, sheet = 1, cols = 6:8, widths = "auto")

addStyle(wb, 1, style = s1, rows = 2:(nrow(df)+1), cols = 1, gridExpand = FALSE)
addStyle(wb, 1, style = s2, rows = 2:(nrow(df)+1), cols = 2, gridExpand = FALSE)

saveWorkbook(wb, paste0("test.xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
```